# How can I make these names into email form?

Tags: python

I need to put these names into email form.

For example, I have these names list:

```
saint christopher
lebron james
kevin durant
kyrie andrew irving
d j khaled
bloodpop(r)
```

And need to get the result of:

```
schristo@gmail.com
ljames@gmail.com
kdurant@gmail.com
kairving@gmail.com
djkhaled@gmail.com
bloodpop@gmail.com
```

I have made them into lower case and try to use split() but doesn't work.

I have done:

```
fname = input("Enter filename:")
infile = open(fname, "r")

for line in infile:
    first,last = line.lower().split()
    uname = (first[0] + last[:8])
    print(uname)
infile.close()
```

I get an error that says:

```
  first,last = line.lower().split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: so it just takes the 1st letter of the first, and/or middle name? The last name stays the same?

Comment: It's unclear how the names map. Why `schristo` and not `schristopher`? Why `bloodpop` and not `b` or `bloodpop(r)`?

Comment: @AdamSmith I was confused about that too lol

Comment: @kstullich Yes!

Comment: @kstullich if that were the case, the last email *should* be `bloodpop(r)@gmail.com`, so even though OP confirms that's the correct answer, he's wrong ;)

Comment: @AdamSmith Well for schristo , I can only list 8 words at the most. For bloodpop...I don't understand that too... does anyone have an idea?

Comment: @HeeRaChoi ah ha -- 8 chars max

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes!

Comment: `(r)` probably indicates to leave the name as it is.

Comment: @Mark Got it! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use splat tuple assignment to split the firsts away from the last, grab the first initials of each of the `firsts`, then join them with the last and slice off the first 8 characters.

```
def make_username(name, suffix="gmail.com"):
    *firsts, last = name.lower().split()
    initials = ''.join([s[0] for s in firsts])
    username = ''.join([initials, last])[:8]
    return f"{username}@{suffix}"
```

Comment: what does s stand for?

Comment: In this case it's a stand-in for "string", but you could use any letter there (and in fact I originally wrote `n` for "name", but `n` is more commonly used as a number). That's a list comprehension. It iterates over each element in `firsts` (all the non-last names) and makes a new list out of them. In this case it calls each element `s`, then makes a new list out of the `s[0]`s.

Comment: If the `(r)` suffix indicates to leave the name as it is, consider adding `if name[-3:] == '(r)': return f"{name[:-3][:8]}@{suffix}"`

Comment: @Mark I think you're wrong about that. There's nothing to make me believe that the `(r)` suffix means anything other than representing the registered trademark symbol at the end of the artist's name.

Comment: From [his wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BloodPop): "Michael Tucker[1][2] (born in Kansas City on August 15, 1990),[3] known professionally as BloodPop®" (note the registered trademark symbol as being part of his "brand" if you will)

Comment: @AdamSmith You are probably correct. With some context, my assumption does make less sense.

Comment: How do you do the splat tuple assignment to split the firsts away from the last?

Comment: @HeeRaChoi I don't understand the question. See my code above (`*firsts, last = ...`)

Comment: If I do what you did I get an error that says, "too many values to unpack"
so I tried to solve by stating first =[0] last=[0], before *first, last =... 
but does not work

Comment: @HeeRaChoi What version of Python are you running?

Comment: @Adam Smith Python 3.6.2

Comment: @HeeRaChoi then I think you've written a typo, because `*firsts, last = ...` handles any number of values to unpack.

Comment: @AdamSmith I have edited my post. Can you look over?

Comment: Yup, that's a typo alright! Short of typing it into your keyboard for you I'm not sure what more help I can be. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
email_name = 'saint christopher'

import string

new_str = string.replace(email_name,' ', '')
print(new_str)
```

it gives you out put: 
    saintchristopher

Comment: "it gives you out put: saintchristopher" which is wrong.